# Register component with castle LifestylePerWebRequest mvc5

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I'm trying to register a component with castle LifestylePerWebRequest method and keep getting the error:
"Looks like you forgot to register the http module Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule
To fix this add
"

Although I have registered the castle module in the web.config file
does it related to the fact that I'm working with Mvc-5?

my code:

```
container.Register(Component.For<ISiteTranslator>().UsingFactoryMethod(MvcApplication.TranslationFactory).LifestylePerWebRequest());

container.Resolve<ISiteTranslator>();
```

web config:

```
<system.webServer>    
    <modules >         
            <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor" />                     
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is this on IIS7? [From the Castle documentation](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=LifeStyles&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1):

> In order to function properly per web request requires a IHttpModule to be
> registered in your web.config:
> …
>
> if you're running on IIS7 you may need to register it in system.webServer/modules section instead.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <modules>
         <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" 
         type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, 
               Castle.Windsor" />
      </modules>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```